# Ubuntu sees 3 out of 4GB of RAM on PAE supported 32bit system

Tags: ram, pae

I have 4 gigs of memory inside my laptop but only 3 gigs are showing up and PAE is supported as shown below.

Why can't I use all 4 gigs of memory even though my 32 bit system shows that it supports PAE?

KERNEL AND COMPUTER

```
$ uname -a
Linux Toshiba-Gnome 3.19.0-10-generic #10-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 23 16:16:45 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

I have two RAM slots filled each with a 2gig memory card but as you see below I'm only using 3 gigs for some reason.

```
~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3019       2631        388        354        115       1277
-/+ buffers/cache:       1237       1781
Swap:         4095         29       4066
```

Detailed RAM information

```
$ sudo dmidecode --type memory
[sudo] password for XXXXXXX: 
# dmidecode 2.12
SMBIOS 2.4 present.

Handle 0x0013, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 2 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x0014, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0013
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 32 bits
    Data Width: 32 bits
    Size: 2048 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: 1
    Locator: M1
    Bank Locator: Bank 0
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 667 MHz
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified

Handle 0x0015, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0013
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 32 bits
    Data Width: 32 bits
    Size: 2048 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: 1
    Locator: M2
    Bank Locator: Bank 1
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 667 MHz
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
```

CPU Information

```
 $ grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo
    2
    hoshi@Toshiba-Gnome:~$ 
    hoshi@Toshiba-Gnome:~$ 
    hoshi@Toshiba-Gnome:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
    processor   : 0
    vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
    cpu family  : 6
    model       : 14
    model name  : Genuine Intel(R) CPU           T2050  @ 1.60GHz
    stepping    : 8
    microcode   : 0x39
    cpu MHz     : 800.000
    cache size  : 2048 KB
    physical id : 0
    siblings    : 2
    core id     : 0
    cpu cores   : 2
    apicid      : 0
    initial apicid  : 0
    fdiv_bug    : no
    f00f_bug    : no
    coma_bug    : no
    fpu     : yes
    fpu_exception   : yes
    cpuid level : 10
    wp      : yes
    flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx constant_tsc arch_perfmon bts aperfmperf pni monitor est tm2 xtpr pdcm dtherm
    bugs        :
    bogomips    : 3191.80
    clflush size    : 64
    cache_alignment : 64
    address sizes   : 32 bits physical, 32 bits virtual
    power management:

    processor   : 1
    vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
    cpu family  : 6
    model       : 14
    model name  : Genuine Intel(R) CPU           T2050  @ 1.60GHz
    stepping    : 8
    microcode   : 0x39
    cpu MHz     : 1333.000
    cache size  : 2048 KB
    physical id : 0
    siblings    : 2
    core id     : 1
    cpu cores   : 2
    apicid      : 1
    initial apicid  : 1
    fdiv_bug    : no
    f00f_bug    : no
    coma_bug    : no
    fpu     : yes
    fpu_exception   : yes
    cpuid level : 10
    wp      : yes
    flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx constant_tsc arch_perfmon bts aperfmperf pni monitor est tm2 xtpr pdcm dtherm
    bugs        :
    bogomips    : 3191.80
    clflush size    : 64
    cache_alignment : 64
    address sizes   : 32 bits physical, 32 bits virtual
    power management:
```

Someone said that my display may be taking 1gig of memory. I check with the following commands and it seems that my display is only taking about 250mb of memory.

```
$ lspci -v -s 00:02.0
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device ff10
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f0a00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    I/O ports at 1800 [size=8]
    Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0b00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915

hoshi@Toshiba-Gnome:~$ 
hoshi@Toshiba-Gnome:~$ 
hoshi@Toshiba-Gnome:~$ lspci -v -s 00:02.1
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device ff10
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at f0a80000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Please let me know if I can provide any other information.

Comment: PAE is among the available CPU flags, no need to enable it.

Comment: But it is obviously not enabled or I would be getting 4 gigs of ram. Is there any way to force enable it.

Comment: Plus you can see that my CPU supports PAE. On older versions of Ubuntu It used to work just fine. Is there any way to force enable it.

Comment: This kernel is the Vivid kernel which is an in development version and off topic in askUbuntu.

Answer (score 1):

`PAE`, as stated in the comments, is enabled already. You're probably using an integrated video card without dedicated memory, which is taking up some of the RAM space (1GB) to operate. From Wikipedia.com:

> A side effect of this is that when some RAM is allocated for graphics, it becomes effectively unavailable for anything else, so an example computer with 512 MiB RAM set up with 64MiB graphics RAM will appear to the operating system and user to only have 448 MiB RAM installed.

The only way to solve this, unfortunately, is to switch to a new video card with dedicated memory.

Comment: Is there a way to PROVE that my video card is doing this?

Comment: I did some magic to check how much memory my video card is using ... seems to be only 250mb.

Comment: Sorry, I posted that information in my original question.

Comment: @JoshuaRobison I'm trying to figure out a smart way to check this, but nothing comes to mind, the best I can think of is to just run `sudo lshw -C video` to see your card's manufacturer and model and to google for it to see if it carries some dedicated memory or not